# Change the Company Name

Tags: iphone, app-store, app-store-connect

Is there any way to change your company name that is displayed in the app store from iTunesConnect?

Any answers will be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using a different company name for iPhone app distribution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435809/using-a-different-company-name-for-iphone-app-distribution) Also see [Upgrading the company name of an app that has been submitted to the app store](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895151/upgrading-the-company-name-of-an-app-that-has-been-submitted-to-the-app-store).

Answer (score 2):

The only way to change the company name is via a very tedious process through Apple. Use the "contact us" forms on the iTunes Connect site.